# Copy a series of cell into multiple worksheets named via a cell

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, series

thank you for taking the time to look at my VBA macro. My goal with this macro is to copy a row of cells (e7:i7) to a duplicated workbook that has a template pasted in the worksheet and named via a series of cells (c7). Then repeating that process with the next row of cells (e8:i8) using (c8) as its name.

I have the template worksheet duplication working, I have the worksheet naming working. My issue is copying the cells from "Worksheet" to the newly named worksheet that uses (c7)series as its name.

I am getting

> "Run-time Error '9':
>   Subscript out of range

I appreciate your help on this as this is my first VBA project.

```
Sub NEWSAVINGSTEST1()
'
' NEWSAVINGSTEST1 Macro
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEWSAVINGS")

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("c7")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets("NEWSAVINGS").Select
Sheets("NEWSAVINGS").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
'ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select ("Master") ' just select the sheet
Source.Copy
Set MyRange2 = Sheets("Master").Range("e7:l7")
Set MyRange2 = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
ActiveSheet.Range("d11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next MyCell

'
End Sub
```

Comment: `worksheet` has got to be the worst name for a worksheet XD

Comment: Absolutely right, I have changed it to "Master"

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe for the below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select ("Worksheet")
```

You actually wanted something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Select
```

Comment: Unfortunately it now gives me a error: of '424' It does not compile correctly the

    Source.Copy

Command correctly

Comment: It doesn't look like you set Source to anything?  Maybe you should eliminate that line and add a "MyRange2.Copy" after you finished setting the "MyRange2" range.  I guess it depends on what you are trying to copy?